# Set permanent button image after tap

Tags: ios, image, button, touch, control-state

i've programmatically created a button with an image for normalState.
But I want to set a new button image when the button is pressed (the new image should be displayed for the rest of the time). I tried something, but it only works during tapping. So the button shows its old image after tapping again.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
button.frame = CGRectMake(15.0f, 32.0f, 24.0f, 20.0f);
[cell addSubview:button];
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this it will helps you.

```
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(15.0f, 32.0f, 24.0f, 20.0f);

    // ----------- Add this line in your code -------
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:button];


    - (void)btnPressed:(UIButton *)sender
    {
          [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the setting in the target of the button. Add the following code:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and set the image in that method for `UIControlStateNormal`:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```